# Obtaining cellsite gps location on Blackberry Curve 8520

Tags: blackberry, gps

Details of my phone:

```
  Model:Blackberry Curve 8520
  Version :5.0.0.1036
  data services :on
```

When I am installing google maps I am able to see the location ,so there is a chance of obtaining the current location using this phone.

I am trying to develop an application which will show the current location of the phone,by using the cell site locations because this phone model does not have an in-built GPS device.

I am using the following code:

```
   BlackBerryCriteria bc=new BlackBerryCriteria(GPSInfo. GPS_MODE_CELLSITE );        
   try {
    LocationProvider lp=LocationProvider.getInstance(bc);
           if(lp !=null)
           {
            Location loc=lp.getLocation(-1);
            add (new EditField(loc.getQualifiedCoordinates().getLatitude()+"\n"+loc.getQualifiedCoordinates().getLongitude(),""));
           }
    else
         {
        add(new EditField("unable to find the location provider", ""));
         }
    } catch (LocationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }}
```

I am installing the alx file on the bb phone using desktop manager.

On starting the application it is giving me an Uncaught exception:

> NET.RIM.DEVICE.API.SYSTEM.UNSupportedOperationException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The device might currently not support GPS_MODE_CELLSITE. Check using

```
 GPSInfo.isGPSModeAvailable(GPS_MODE_CELLSITE)
```

and use another mode if neccessary.

It might not support GPS_MODE_CELLSITE because:

- There is no valid SIM card in your phone (ok, i assume you have one :)
- Check if your device and carrier have available GPS mode you are using ([here](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800703/What_Is_-_The_BlackBerry_smartphone_models_and_their_corresponding_GPS_capabilities.html?nodeid=1371352&vernum=0))
- If your carrier is Verizone, check for Verizon GPSSettings signing requirement
- Your APN settings are not correct (Options > Device > Advanced Settings > TCP IP)
- You don't have a BlackBerry Service Plan (not too sure about that one)