# cellsite GPS in bb curve 8520

Tags: blackberry, gps

can anyone give me a code which obtains the cellsite gps location for black berry 8520 os version 5.0.
details of my phone:

```
  model:bb curve 8520
  version :5.0.0.1036
  carrier:airtel (post paid )
  location :Andhra Pradesh ,India
  data services :on
```

when i am installing google maps i am able to see the location ,so there is a chance of obtaining the current location using this phone.

I am trying to develop an application which will show the current location of the phone,by using the cell site locations because this phone model does not have a in-built GPS device.

please its urgent
i have tried several examples on internet but in vain.

thanks in advance

this is the code i have used:

```
        BlackBerryCriteria bc=new BlackBerryCriteria(GPSInfo.       GPS_MODE_CELLSITE );        
  try {
      LocationProvider lp=LocationProvider.getInstance(bc);
         if(lp !=null)
       {
        Location loc=lp.getLocation(-1);
        add (new EditField(loc.getQualifiedCoordinates().getLatitude()+"\n"+loc.getQualifiedCoordinates().getLongitude(),""));
       }
else
     {
    add(new EditField("unable to find the location provider", ""));
     }
} catch (LocationException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}}
```

but i am geeting an uncaught exception
net.rim.device.api.UnsupportedOperationException.

please helpme its urgent

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Blackberry doesn't provide Maps in india.
You can only get Lat Lon from your device.

When you trying to get the lat lon then go to the open space place.
Don't try in the office or in room or in buiding.

Go to [Gps Lat Lon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145044/get-gps-location-on-blackberry)

Comment: i have downloaded google maps into my mobile and i am able to view the current location in the maps .I am not saying that i have used black berry maps. please go through this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816724/obtaining-cellsite-gps-location-on-black-berry-curve-8520

Comment: nope i downloaded google maps from the google server and i have used it to find the location.          I want to develop an application which will find the current lat-long info in a black berry 8520 device which does not have a in-built GPS receiver.

Comment: I think cell site method is the only way to do it.

Comment: i have now edited the question and i have put the code i have used.

Comment: Try the link which i edit in my answer.
And you will get the Lat Lon with this code.
Because i get the lat lon with the same code.

Comment: i am getting the myLocatioProvider value as null.i have changed the iscostallowed as true still the location provider varible is null. remember i am using black berry 8520 which is having no in-built gps device. it should obtain location from the network provider

Comment: i hope you understood the problem .the code is working fine when the mobile is having an inbuilt gps device, like 9700 - i have tested it but not on 8520 which is not having the gps device

Comment: the other code you gave is also not giving the location both the provider and  the _locationProvider variables are null so nolocation.

Comment: I am using a vodafone sim now,any issues with that.        I have also tried with airtel sim post paid. I have heard that cellsite location service is not available in India is it true?

Comment: Sorry i have not the answer of this question.
i don't know what is the problem now.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import java.util.TimerTask;
import javax.microedition.location.Criteria;
import javax.microedition.location.Location;
import javax.microedition.location.LocationException;
import javax.microedition.location.LocationListener;
import javax.microedition.location.LocationProvider;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.Dialog;

public class HandleMAPAPI 
{
    static boolean _isCancel = false;
    private Criteria criteria;
    double latitude ,longitude;
    TimerTask _loadinglatlon;
    private LocationProvider provider,_locationProvider;
    Location location = null;
    boolean _islatlong;

    public HandleMAPAPI()
    {
        startLocationUpdate() ;
    }

    public void startLocationUpdate() 
    {
        try{
            _locationProvider = LocationProvider.getInstance(null);
            if (_locationProvider != null) {
                _locationProvider.setLocationListener(
                        new LocationListenerImpl(), 1, 1, 1);
            } else {
                setupCriteria();
                setupProvider();
            }
        }catch(LocationException le){
            System.out.println("----Exception Of Location--"+le);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Initializes criteria according to the mode selected by the user.
     */
    private void setupCriteria() {
        criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
        criteria.setHorizontalAccuracy(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);
        criteria.setVerticalAccuracy(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);
        criteria.setPreferredPowerConsumption(Criteria.POWER_USAGE_LOW);
    }

    /**
     * Initializes LocationProvider based on specified mode and Criteria.
     */
    private void setupProvider() {
        try {

            // Just to give setupPDE and criteria setup.. some time. This may
            // not be needed at all.
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (Throwable e) {
               System.out.println(e.toString());
            }

            provider = LocationProvider.getInstance(criteria);
            if (provider != null) {
                singleFixLocationUpdate();
            } else {
                //Utilites.log("Provider unavailable for that Criteria");
            }
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            System.out.println(t.toString());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Gets a single fix by calling LocationProvider.getLocation().
     */

    private void singleFixLocationUpdate() {
        try {
            location = provider.getLocation(-1);
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            System.out.println("InterruptedException thrown by getLocation(): "
                    + ie.toString());
        } catch (LocationException le) {
            System.out.println("LocationException thrown by getLocation(): "
                    + le.toString());
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            System.out.println(t.toString());
        }
        if (location != null) {
            if (location.isValid()) {
                System.out.println("Valid single fix: "
                        + location.getQualifiedCoordinates().getLatitude()
                        + ", "
                        + location.getQualifiedCoordinates().getLongitude()
                        + " "
                        + location.getQualifiedCoordinates().getAltitude());

                longitude= location.getQualifiedCoordinates()
                        .getLongitude();
                latitude = location.getQualifiedCoordinates()
                        .getLatitude();

                if (longitude != 0.0 && latitude != 0.0) {

                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("----Cell site Sunnyvale--");
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid single fix");
            }
        } else 
        {
            closeLoading("null", "null");
            Dialog.alert("No GPS Found");
        }
    }

    public  class LocationListenerImpl implements LocationListener {
        public void locationUpdated(LocationProvider provider, Location location) {
            System.out.println("---Location Updated-----");
            if (location.isValid()) {

                System.out.println("---Location Valid----");
                longitude = location.getQualifiedCoordinates()
                        .getLongitude();
                latitude= location.getQualifiedCoordinates()
                        .getLatitude();
                if (longitude != 0.0 && latitude != 0.0) {

                } else {
                    System.out.println("--Cellsite valide=-----");
                        setupCriteria();
                        setupProvider();
                }
                _locationProvider.setLocationListener(null, 0, 0, 0);

            }else{
                System.out.println("else NOT valid--Cellsite valide=-----");
                setupCriteria();
                setupProvider();
            }
            System.out.println("---Location Not Valid----");
        }

        public void providerStateChanged(LocationProvider provider, int newState) {}
    }       
}
```

Comment: This code will give the lat lon for both Gps enable device and Non-gps device.